# Android 11，crash in skia/src/ops/GrorvalOpFactory.cpp, Help me see why

Tags: android, skia

https://github.com/google/skia/blob/master/src/gpu/ops/GrOvalOpFactory.cpp

cras in this function

```cpp
this->setVertexAttributes(&fInPosition, 7);
```

After tracking and positioning, the problem is that the next pointer position of fInPosition is not a legal Attribute, which means

```cpp
     Attribute fInPosition;
     Attribute fInColor;
     Attribute fInCircleEdge;
     // Optional attributes.
     Attribute fInClipPlane;
     Attribute fInIsectPlane;
     Attribute fInUnionPlane;
     Attribute fInRoundCapCenters;
```

These attributes are not allocated to contiguous memory.

But I added a line of log printing to the above code, and the crash disappeared. After checking the assembly code, I found that printing the log would change the compilation method. I would like to ask what changes caused by Android 11 compilation

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved. The memory is not connected due to the incorrect PGO copying the data of the input parameter of the function to other registers.